# Maximum Value of $g(x)=(8+x)^3(8-x)^4$

Tags: functions

I think there can not be a maximum value of this, as if I plug $x=$1000, it will increase the value of the function in leaps and bounds. The answer says that the maximum value will occur at $x=-8/7$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes Moo. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a local maximum and no global maximum - do a plot to see that.

Comment: I plotted it, the max value is going towards the infinite. X has to be a real value as well. How do we know whether question asks about local or global maximum?

Comment: That has to be given, generally, to avoid such ambiguities. I was actually writing a comment that hinted at how the question is poorly phrased for this reason.

Comment: Yes,I think the question is not clear for the same reason. 
The solution aslo says that the max value shall be at the point where $(8+x)/3$ shoule be equal to $(8-x)/4$.

Comment: Are you familiar with differentiation / the notion of maxima,minima of a differentiable function?

Comment: Not much. If you could share some material/link, I would go through it and then probably, I should be able to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

$p(x)= (8+x)^3(8-x)^4$ is a polynomial of degree $7$,

with leading term $x^7$.

1)No abs. maximum ,no abs. minimum .  $(x \rightarrow \pm \infty )$

2) $3$ zeroes at $x=-8$, $4$ zeroes at $x=8$.

3)$ -8 <x < 8$ :  $p(x) >0$.
(Has a relative maximum).

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$g(x)=(8+x)^3(8-x)^4\implies g'(x)=3(8+x)^2(8-x)^4-4(8+x)^3(8-x)^3=0$$

$$3(8+x)^2(8-x)^4=4(8+x)^3(8-x)^3$$

which is true when

- $x=\pm 8$
- $3(8-x)=4(8+x) \implies 7x=-8 \implies x=-\frac87$

and the latter is a local maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wavy curve approach to find the range in which the local extremas and global extremas.

The wavy curve method is specifically used for polynomial equations.

Using this method you can easily come to know that there is no global maxima and global minima. However in the range (-8,8) there exists a local maxima. That point is x=-8/7